# How do I get rid of it? Bang & Olufsen tiny panel

Tags: windows

There is a tiny panel on my screen, and ever since I started online classes on Zoom and it won't go away!

First, there is the B&O logo, then the "Incoming Noise cancellation" button, then the "Microphone Noise cancellation" button, then the "Change sound Mode", then the close button!

Whenever I click on the "Close" button, it just makes it the "B&O" Logo again and goes to the middle top of my screen!

How do I get rid of it?

[image: Windows]